# Given a binary search tree and a number, find a path whose node's data added to be the given number.

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree, binary-tree, binary-search

Given a binary search tree and a number, find if there is a path from root to a leaf such that all numbers on the path added up to be the given number.

I know how to do it by recursively. But, I prefer an iterative solution.

If we iterate from root to a leaf each time, there will be overlap because some paths may have  overlap.

What if the tree is not binary search ?

Thanks

Comment: There are several ways of doing it recursively. Which one are you using? You say "all numbers", but you did not say where these numbers are, in the edges, or in the nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Basically this problem can be solved using Dynamic Programming on tree to avoid those overlapping paths.

The basic idea is to keep track of the possible lengths from each leaf to a given node in a table `f[node]`. If we implement it in a 2-dimensional boolean array, it is something like `f[node][len]`, which indicates whether there is a path from a leaf to `node` with length equal to `len`. We can also use a `vector<int>` to store the value in each `f[node]` instead of using a boolean array. No matter what kind of representation you use, the way you calculate between different `f` are straightforward, in the form of

```
f[node] is the union of f[node->left] + len_left[node] and f[node->right] + len_right[node].
```

This is the case of binary tree, but it is really easy to extend it to non-binary-tree cases.

If there is anything unclear, please feel free to comment.

Answer (score 0):

Anything you can do recursively, you can also do iteratively. However you are not having performance issues with the recursive solution, then I would leave it as is. It would more likely than not be more difficult to code/read if you try to do it iteratively.

However if you insist, you can transform your recursive solution into an iterative one by using a stack. Every time you make a recursive call, push the state variables in your current function call onto the stack. When you are done with a call, pop off the variables.

Comment: if the tree is not balanced, we may have stack overflow in recursion. So, iterative solution is preferred. But, I still cannot understand your algorithm. Would you please say it with pseudo code ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

For BST:

```
Node current,final = (initialize)
List nodesInPath;
nodesInPath.add(current);
while(current != final) {
    List childrenNodes = current.children;
    if(noChildren) noSolution;
    if(current < final) {
        //choose right child if there is one, otherwise no solution
        current = children[right];
    } else if(current > final){
        //choose left child if there is one, otherwise no solution
        current = children[left];         
    } 
    nodesInPath.add(current);
}
check sum in the nodesInPath
```

However, for non BST you should apply a solution using dynamic programming as [derekhh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/634042/derekhh) suggests if you don't want to calculate same paths over and over again. I think, you can store the total length between a certain processed node and the root node. You calculate the distances when you expand them. Then you would apply `Breadth-first search` to not to traverse same paths again and use previously computed total distances. The algorithm comes to my mind is a little complex, sorry but not have enough time to write it.