# Re: Given a binary search tree and a number, find a path whose node's data added to be the given number

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, binary-search, binary-search-tree

I saw this problem: [Given a binary search tree and a number, find a path whose node's data added to be the given number.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659736/given-a-binary-search-tree-and-a-number-find-a-path-whose-nodes-data-added-to) .

On it it says that Given a binary search tree and a number, find if there is a path from root to a leaf such that all numbers on the path added up to be the given number.

Everyone on that thread seems to know the recursive way to do this.

Am I missing something? How do you solve this recursively? Do you have to brute force the whole tree?

Can someone give an outline (rough idea) on how to do this?

Comment: Is the tree sorted? If it's not, then brute force is the only practical choice. Given a sorted tree, you can do certain optimizations by eliminate any "right-hand" branches that would make you exceed the required total.

Comment: Why don't you ask the original poster directly? he claimed to know how to do it.

Comment: @MarcB: binary search tree is sorted by definition

Comment: If the tree contains only +ve numbers, this is straightforward.  Just do a depth-first walk, keeping track of the current sum from the root.  As soon as you overshoot the target, then backtrack.  Not sure how to extend this to -ve numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recursive approach is done something like `f(node, len)` and when you go through left or right node you change it to `f(node->left, len-left)` or `f(node->right,len-right)`. When you go down to the leaf you check whether the current `len==0` and all is done.

This recursive approach actually is the same as brute force, however, you can use the memoization technique to make it faster, just as what I said in that post.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much as you'd expect: do a traversal of the tree, where the call on a child node has a target value of the caller's target value minus the caller's value; search stops when a leaf has the target value.  Because it is a BST, you'll be able to cut off searching the right child whenever the target for that child is less than the value of the current node (b/c everything in the right subtree is no less).